# PHP Array get the parameter

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question. My array looks like this

```
Array (
  [27] => Array (
    [parent_id] => 26
    [name] => asd
    [item_id] => 27
  )
)
```

I want to echo the name but I don't know how, I have tried multiple foreaches and `$array['name']`, `$array[1]['name']` but nothing works.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: `echo $myArray[27]['name']`

Answer (score 1):

`$array[27]['name']` is ok try again

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I have the solution it was $array[27]['name'].

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
print_r($array[27]);
```

which will show the entire array.